# Append json data to end of url

Tags: jquery, json

I have some json data that I need to append to the end of a url

```
var myData = "https://example.com/json"

    $.getJSON(myData, function(data) {

       var url = data[0]['link'];

       $('#some-div').html('<div data-href="https://example.com/+urlhere+">');

    });
```

Not sure how I can do this. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use string concatenation. Also, encode it with `encodeURIComponent`

```
var myData = "https://example.com/json"

$.getJSON(myData, function(data) {
   var url = data[0]['link'];
   $('#some-div').html('<div data-href="https://example.com/"' + encodeURIComponent(url) + '">');
});
```